# ExoPlayer: how to display subtitles with useController=false?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, http-live-streaming, exoplayer, android-media3

**Using AndroidX Media3 ExoPlayer with `useController=false` and custom Jetpack Compose controls, how to make HLS embedded video subtitles automatically show up and provide a button to select/disable them?**

NB: this is not the same question as [How to display HLS subtitles with ExoPlayer 3 and Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76397202/how-to-display-hls-subtitles-with-exoplayer-3-and-compose). Thanks for your help!

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyPlayer() {
  val hlsUri = Uri.parse("https://some.website/video.m3u8")
  val context = LocalContext.current
  val player: ExoPlayer = remember {
    ExoPlayer.Builder(context)
        .build()
        .apply {
            setMediaItem(MediaItem.fromUri(hlsUri))
            prepare()
        }
    }

    AndroidView(
        factory = {
            PlayerView(context).apply {
                this.player = player
                useController = false // <- because of this, setShowSubtitleButton(true) is not a solution
                layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT)
            }
        }
    )

    // Custom Jetpack Compose controls (play, pause, show/hide subtitles, etc) are added below 
    // ...
}
```

Dependencies:

```ini
# gradle/libs.versions.toml

androidXMedia = "1.1.0"
androidx-media-player = { group = "androidx.media3", name = "media3-exoplayer", version.ref = "androidXMedia" }
androidx-media-ui = { group = "androidx.media3", name = "media3-ui", version.ref = "androidXMedia" }
androidx-media-hls = { group = "androidx.media3", name = "media3-exoplayer-hls", version.ref = "androidXMedia" }
```

```kotlin
// app/build.gradle.kts

dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation(libs.androidx.media.player)
    implementation(libs.androidx.media.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.media.hls)
}
```

Here is what the HLS file looks like:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",NAME="English",LANGUAGE="en",URI="https://.../playlist.m3u8",AUTOSELECT=YES,DEFAULT=NO
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",NAME="Français",LANGUAGE="fr",URI="https://.../playlist.m3u8",AUTOSELECT=YES,DEFAULT=NO

#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio-medium",NAME="audio",AUTOSELECT=YES,DEFAULT=YES,CHANNELS="2",URI="https://.../playlist.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio-high",NAME="audio",AUTOSELECT=YES,DEFAULT=YES,CHANNELS="2",URI="https://.../playlist.m3u8"

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:SUBTITLES="subs",BANDWIDTH=2255226,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=1578000,RESOLUTION=1280x720,FRAME-RATE=24.000,CODECS="avc1.640020,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="audio-high"
https://.../playlist.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:SUBTITLES="subs",BANDWIDTH=698963,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=537000,RESOLUTION=640x360,FRAME-RATE=24.000,CODECS="avc1.64001E,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="audio-medium"
https://.../playlist.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:SUBTITLES="subs",BANDWIDTH=463242,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=332000,RESOLUTION=426x240,FRAME-RATE=24.000,CODECS="avc1.640015,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="audio-medium"
https://.../playlist.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:SUBTITLES="subs",BANDWIDTH=5496152,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=4096000,RESOLUTION=1920x1080,FRAME-RATE=24.000,CODECS="avc1.640028,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="audio-high"
https://.../playlist.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:SUBTITLES="subs",BANDWIDTH=1440054,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=965000,RESOLUTION=960x540,FRAME-RATE=24.000,CODECS="avc1.64001F,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="audio-medium"
https://.../playlist.m3u8
```